# Details sections displaying in wrong order

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using a database source as a text file, and display the information in six sequential Details Sections:

> details1
>
> details2
>
> details3
>
> details4
>
> details5
>
> details6

`details1` had too many fields to display on a single row, so I added the last 3 remaining sections.

Now when I generate the report, the fields display in the wrong order. `details4` shows after `details1` as both has the same formula. Then `details2` and `details5` show, then `details3` and `details6`. The report gets messy.

Is there any way where in I can display all six sections in their original order?

Comment: Are the six fields supposed to be displayed left to right? Or top to bottom.

Comment: Best option is to increase the width of design to accomidate all fields...you can do it by going to page setup in file menu

Comment: Why dont you create duplicate formulas instead of using same one and then place it where you want.

Comment: @4444 all the details section has more then 5 fields to be displayed. And Details1 to details6 should display top to bottom.

Comment: @Siva thanks for the suggestion but the printer doesnt support Leagel format option.

Comment: @aMazing my formula for details1 and details4 is ("if {ReportFields.Chart} = 1 or {ReportFields.RecType} <> 6 then yes"). How do I duplicate this. I am not a crystal report developer. The application I am using is too old and my expertise is on different language. So sorry for the silly question.

Comment: What i mean is create 2 formulae and then add the same content as you have written above in both. Apply one formula in details 1 and other in details 2.

Comment: Both has same formula. Do you want me to write the formula on specific X-2 section?

Comment: My report is showing below

ItemDesc     Prod Qty      PricePerUnit    Location
             ReceivedDT    ReceivedQty     Total

Test         100    50            USA
             01/01/2016    5               500
Test-2       50            10              Canada
             01/05/2016    5               250
Test-3       30            5               USA
             01/10/2016    5               150

Comment: It should look like

Comment: ItemDesc     Prod Qty      PricePerUnit    Location
Test         100    50            USA

             ReceivedDT    ReceivedQty     Total
             01/01/2016    5               500

ItemDesc     Prod Qty      PricePerUnit    Location
Test-2       50            10              Canada
             ReceivedDT    ReceivedQty     Total

             01/05/2016    5               250

ItemDesc     Prod Qty      PricePerUnit    Location
Test-3       30            5               USA
             ReceivedDT    ReceivedQty     Total
             01/10/2016    5               150

Comment: On Detaila I have (ItemDesc     Prod Qty      PricePerUnit    Location)

On Detailb I have (Test         100    50            USA)

On Detailc I have (ReceivedDT    ReceivedQty     Total)

On Detaild I have (             01/01/2016    5               500)

As of now detaila and detailc has the same formula. Detailb and detaild has same formula.


Can you please let me know how do I get the above result. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks every one I have done it.